# Input number HTML5: is there an event which triggers on every step?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

As far as I know, I can only use the *change* event for it, but it's only triggered when I stop increasing/decreasing the number input, not on each and every step taken.

Is there any way to do that? On native javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input): (because anyway [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility) is better than the one for [input type number](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number))

```
$('input[type=number]').on('input', function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#number").on('keyup change', function(e){

});
```

Will work!

Comment: nope. I've just tried it. I mean when you keep pressed the up/down arrows and the value is increasing/decreasing.

Comment: Then use A. Wolff suggestion, with input.